# Kohana ORM, rewriting an ORDER BY and GROUP BY query

Tags: mysql, orm, kohana

I need to get a list of Articles sorted by the latest Comment from a related table joined on article.id = message.article_id using Kohana ORM. I managed to build a query that GROUPS and only then ORDERS:

```
SELECT * 
FROM  `articles` 
LEFT JOIN  `comments` ON (  `articles`.`id` =  `comments`.`article_id` ) 
GROUP BY  `comments`.`item_id` 
ORDER BY  `datetime` DESC
```

The query I am trying to build is:

```
SELECT * FROM `articles` LEFT JOIN 
(SELECT article_id, MAX(datetime) as datetime FROM comments GROUP BY (article_id)) 
AS b ON `articles`.`id` = b.`article_id` 
ORDER BY datetime
```

I have no idea how to rewrite it into Kohana ORM... (and I can't avoid ORM because there is a ton of code that depends on it)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$subquery = DB::select('article_id', array('MAX("datetime")','datetime'))
    ->from('comments')
    ->group_by('article_id');

$s = ORM::factory('article')
    ->join(array($subquery, 'b'), 'LEFT')
    ->on('article.id','=','b.article_id')
    ->order_by('datetime')
    ->find_all();
```

This is the translation of your query, I'm not really sure if it will work

Comment: Thanks man, it worked. In my defence, Kohana docs clearly state join()'s first parameter has to be a string and I believed them ).

Answer (score 1):

```
ORM::factory('article')->join('comments', 'LEFT')->on('article.id', '=', 'comments.article_id')->group_by('comments.id')->order_by('date', 'DESC')->find_all()->as_array();
```

This generates sql as :

> SELECT `article`.* FROM `articles` AS `article` LEFT JOIN `comments`
>   ON (`article`.`id` = `comments`.`article_id`) GROUP BY `comments`.`id`
>   ORDER BY `date` DESC

which matches your first query.

I'm not sure how to use nested query in ORM but there is [Query builder](http://kohanaframework.org/3.2/guide/database/query/builder) in kohana which should do the trick for you.